# Class function is changed global variables

Tags: python, function, class, global-variables, local

```
I = [[140,50],[140,80],[140,110],[140,140]]
O = [[140,50],[170,50],[140,80],[170,80]]

tomato = [I,O]


class Change():
    def __init__(self,):
        self.liste = []
    
def change(self,):
    self.liste.extend(tomato[0])
    for i in range(10):
        self.liste[0][0] += 10
```

That class when ı use change method this changing global tomato[0] how can i fix that.

Comment: You are storing a _reference_ to `tomato` in `liste`. So when you change one element in the latter, it changes in the former as well

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I clone a list so that it doesn't change unexpectedly after assignment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2612802/how-do-i-clone-a-list-so-that-it-doesnt-change-unexpectedly-after-assignment)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified example illustrating your problem.

Initialize a list object `x`:

```py
x = [0]
```

Initialize another list `a`, storing the previous list `x` in it as an element:

```py
a = [x]
```

Initialize yet another list `b` and add the elements from `a` to it;
the only element in `a` is the list object `x`, which is now appended to `b`:

```py
b = []
b.extend(a)
```

This means that the first (and only) element in `b` is that same list object `x`;
not a clone, not another list with its elements, but **that exact same object**:

```py
print(b[0] is x)
```

Gives `True`.

Notice that I did not check equality, but **identity** using `is`.

This means I can write

```py
b[0][0] = 1
print(x[0] == 1)
```

and get `True`.

Your code is a great example of why it is usually a **terrible** idea to muck around with global variables.